# using DrawerNavigator as main UI, app always enter default item screen without displaying drawer items

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm developing an app with ReactNative and React-Navigation.

And I set a DrawerNavigator as main UI.

But when app launches, it will always enter default item screen, without displaying drawer item.

What am I missing?

---

React-Navigation version: "2.18.2"

code of App.js is as the following. When it runs, App UI shows "page1" instead of showing 2 draw items 'page1' and 'page1'

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Text,  View} from 'react-native';

import { DrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation';


class Page1 extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <View style={{padding: 50}}>
        <Text>
          Page1
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class Page2 extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <View style={{padding: 50}}>
        <Text>
          Page2
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}


const DrawerNavi = DrawerNavigator({
  Page1: {
    screen: Page1
  },
  Page2: {
    screen: Page2
  }
});

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <DrawerNavi />;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const DrawerNavi = createDrawerNavigator({
  Page1: {
    screen: Page1
  },
  Page2: {
    screen: Page2
  }
});
```

You should use createDrawerNavigator instead of DrawerNavigator. I don't actually understand what you mean by "When it runs, App UI shows "page1" instead of showing 2 draw items 'page1' and 'page1'"

The drawerNavigator will show your drawerItems on the left or right (depending on where you want to place it) then you can swipe left/right to access it. It also demands that you have a default screen. You can change this default screen by passing **initialRouteName** to the component.

You can read more about the drawerNavigator here: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/drawer-navigator.html

Comment: if this helped solve your issue, remember to mark as an answer as it will be much appreciated

Comment: yeah, that's it. I haven't noticed I need to swipe left/right to make the drawer show up. Actually my intention is to make the drawer be the entry screen without need to swipe,  Is there any way to do that?

Comment: You could add your buttons directly to the screen, then you could navigate to the pages that you want. And then on those pages add your drawer